# Common eigenvector for 3x3 complex matrix with minimal polynomial of degree at most 2

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

> Let $T_1, T_2: \mathbb{C}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^3$ linear maps. Show that if both linear maps have minimal polynomials of degree at most 2, then there is a vector that is an eigenvector for both $T_1$ and $T_2$.

I'm having trouble solving this problem.
I was able to solve it when $T_1$ or $T_2$ have minimal polynomial of degree 1, but I can't solve it when $T_1$ and $T_2$ both have degree 2 minimal polynomial.
I also tried to relate $T_1$ and $T_2$ to their Jordan canonical form but no luck.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes it does

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Show that if $T : \mathbf{C}^3 \to \mathbf{C}^3$ is a linear map with degree 2 minimal polynomial, then $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $E_{T,\lambda} = \ker(T - \lambda I)$ is at least two-dimensional (consider the Jordan form). Then pick eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ of $T_1$ and $T_2$, respectively, such that $E_{T_1,\lambda_1}$ and $E_{T_2,\lambda_2}$ are both at least two-dimensional. Show that $E_{T_1,\lambda_1} \cap E_{T_2,\lambda_2}$ must be nontrivial by counting dimensions.

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers to duplicate questions.

Comment: @Anne Bauval My bad, didn't know it was a duplicate when I posted.

Comment: If I remember well, the link to the duplicate was present in the comment section far before you posted. May be I am wrong. Anyway, please delete your answer.